# jquery animating dynamic height div

Tags: jquery, animation

quick question. im trying to animate a few things with jquery and although its working, this is the problem im having.

well first heres the code:

```
$(document).ready( function(e){

    // vars
    var question = $('#faqQues');
    var answer = $('#faqAns');  
    var ansCont = $('#faqAnsCont');


    question.click(function(){
         if (answer.css("display") != "none") {
             answer.animate({'height':0}, 500, hmm);

             function hmm() {
                 answer.css("display","none");  
             } 
         } else {
             answer.css("display","block");
             answer.animate({"height":'100'},500);  
         }
    });
});
```

essentially all i want to do be able to click something and it animate its height(up down).
the problem comes in on this code block

```
else {
    answer.css("display","block");
    answer.animate({"height":'100'},500);               
}
```

specifically on this line

```
{"height":'100'}
```

what i want to happen is that it animates back to the divs default height. I dont want to
add a number `(like the 100 above)` height because the divs inner content is always going to change hence the dynamic height but if i remove the height, it breaks. Ive tried a few other things including something like maybe

```
.animate({"height":'**divNameHere**.height()'},500);
```

but although it dont get errors, it doesnt work either lol.

So here i am asking for help. what changes do i need to make to this so that it animates back to whatever that divs height is without directly putting in a number?

Any Tips, code, links etc i'll gladly appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) methods which do exactly what you want ?

Or better yet [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) which handles both ways automatically ?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    // vars
    var question = $('#faqQues');
    var answer = $('#faqAns');
    var ansCont = $('#faqAnsCont');

    question.click(function() {
        answer.slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/5wBeu/

That is all you need..

Comment: thanks. i was looking at the toggle functions earlier but couldnt figure out what to put in the arguments. But this works EXACTLY as what i was trying to achieve. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
.animate({"height": $('**divNameHere**').height()},500);
```

You should leave out the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // vars
    var question = $('#faqQues');
    var answer = $('#faqAns');  
    var ansCont = $('#faqAnsCont');

    question.click(function(){
        if (answer.is(':visible')) {
            answer.animate({height : 'toggle'}, 500, function() {
                answer.hide();
            });
        }else {
            answer.show().animate({height : 'toggle'},500);   
        }
    });
});
```

or just :

```
question.click(function() {
    answer.animate({height : 'toggle'});
});
```